# Adding or Updating XML Node

Tags: c#, xml, tableau-api

I need to either add a couple child nodes or update the  node if it already exists. As you can see from the small sample below, I have one  node with a child nodes, and another without. Say I have a definition coming from a SQL table for both of these, I want to add the value to the  node.

XML

```
<workbook>
<datasources>
    <column datatype='real' name='[CONTRACT_PAYMENT_AMT]' role='measure' type='quantitative'>
        <desc>
          <formatted-text>
            <run>The amount being paid on the contract.</run>
          </formatted-text>
        </desc>
    </column>
    <column datatype='real' name='[CONTRACT_PAYMENT_DATE]' role='measure' type='quantitative'>
    </column>
</datasources>
```

Here is the code I have to just get the name attribute. Columns is the class that could potentially hold datatype, name, role, and type.

```
IEnumerable<string> names = from Columns in XDocument.Load(path).Descendants("column")                                        
                                    select Columns.Attribute("name").Value;

        foreach (string name in names)
        {

        }
```

This was intended to be a start to the method.

I am having trouble thinking about how I can either store the values and update the XML doc, or just look at each node maybe and update as it goes through the document. Any ideas?

EDIT - New code adding new value to the current Run node but not adding a new one..with the definition.

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path);
            var elements = (from column in document.Descendants("column")
                            select new
                                {
                                    AttributeName = column.Attribute("name").Value,
                                    Run = column.Descendants("run").FirstOrDefault() ?? new XElement("run")
                                }).ToList();

            foreach (var item in elements)
            {
                if (item.Run == null) continue;
                else 
                {
                    item.Run.Value = GetVariable(item.AttributeName);
                                     // Getvariable is the method that returns the definition
                }
            }

            document.Save(path);
```

Comment: What do you want to update? Attribute or Just a whole Node?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Based on the name attribute I want to query a table of values for that name, and then add the desc child node(s) with the definition from my table. The definition would sit inside <run><.run>

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple column element with the same value on attribute name?

Comment: @CodeNotFound I dont believe there are multiples of the same attribute name.

Comment: I have a method that will query my table, you just need to add the nodes value to the argument and it will return the associated definition as a string.

Comment: I answered based on what you say here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dot the following logic:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path);
var elements = (from column in document.Descendants("column")
               select new
               {
                    AttributeName = column.Attribute("name").Value,
                    Parent = column,
                    Run = column.Descendants("run").FirstOrDefault()
               }).ToList();

foreach(var item in elements)
{
     XElement run;
     if (item.Run == null)
     {
          run = new XElement("run");
          item.Parent.Add(
              new XElement("desc", 
                  new XElement("formatted-text", 
                      run
                  )
              )
          );
      }
      else
      {
           run = item.Run;
      }

      if(item.AttributeName == "BlaBlaOne")
      {
           run.Value = "Your definition here";
      }
 }

 document.Save(path);
```

Comment: Perfect, that was super simple but I couldn't wrap my head around the syntax. Marked as answer.

Comment: It is updating the Run node but I cannot get it to add one under the Column node. Is it maybe because we dont have the full stack of nodes? I have added new info at the top that is adapted to code you came up with.

Comment: Looks like the item.Parent.Add in the If is not working. I dont have the option of Parent after .Item. I was thinking maybe item.Run.AddBeforeSelf? Thoughts?

Comment: I Added Parent property in the linq query. Make sure you added it in the Select query.